# How can I add a variable to a fragment while merging schemas with Apollo GraphQL

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm working on a project which stitches together multiple remote schemas in a gateway service and extends types from these schemas. This is achieved with `mergeSchemas` from `graphql-tools` where we specify required fragments and custom resolvers to delegate to the relevant schemas. Part of this implementation is:

```
const typeExtensions = `
extend type VsStatistics {
  commonCompetitors(filter: DateRangeFilter): [Player!]!
}
`

const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [ playerSchema, resultsSchema, typeExtensions ],
  resolvers: {
    VsStatistics: {
      commonCompetitors: {
        fragment: `fragment CommonCompetitorsFragment on VsStatistics { commonCompetitorIds }`,
        resolve (parent, _args, context, info) {
          return info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema({
            schema: playerSchema,
            operation: 'query',
            fieldName: 'players',
            args: { idArray: parent.commonCompetitorIds },
            context,
            info
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

commonCompetitorIds is an array of IDs that is available on the VsStatistics object. This stitches fine when I don't need to pass any parameters to the fragment as shown above, but I've since added a filter argument of type `DateRangeFilter` to `commonCompetitorIds`. The `commonCompetitors` type extension takes this filter as an argument and I need to pass it to the fragment somehow in order to apply the filter to `commonCompetitorIds`.
I have tried the following...

```
      commonCompetitors: {
        fragment: `fragment CommonCompetitorsFragment on VsStatistics { commonCompetitorIds(filter: $filter) }`
        ...
```

...in the hope that the parents arguments might be automatically available to the fragment but I get an error saying `Variable "$filter" is not defined`. How can I pass this filter into the fragment in order to get the filtered `commonCompetitorIds` which will then be used in the resolver?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? If so, how? Having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a renewed discussion on this subject in the GraphQL Tools repo here: https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/discussions/1709. In short, the basic capabilities to support this feature were added in v6.0.15.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

> I have circumvented this issue by making two
> `delegateToSchema` requests in my field resolver. The first one
> fetches the plain IDs with variable arguments, and the second one
> performs the standard record stitching. This solution is less than
> ideal because it adds an extra request for IDs, which cascades to
> throwing the stitching request out of phase with other batching going
> to that service. Hopefully we'll get native GraphQL Tools support in
> the future.